# Is there a proper Excel equivalent of SQL NVL?

Tags: excel

Is there any Excel equivalent to the SQL NVL function, which replaces null-like results with a different specified value, that doesn't require calculating the value more than once or storing the value in another cell?

Example of calculating a value twice:

```
=IF(ISERROR(A1/B1),"",A1/B1)
```

Dividing one value by another is simple; but if the calculation is more complicated then I don't want to include it twice, at least to make the formula more readable.

Comment: Use `IFERROR()` function.

Comment: @Harun24hr: I had the same problem: the `IF()` function has an `else`- part, but the `IFERROR()` hasn't. I didn't realise that the `else`-part of the `IFERROR()` is the result of the calculation :-)